# Function does not work - shows 0

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple function that counts a company bonus. For some reason, it shows 0 and does not give an answer.

```
Function insurancebonus(penetration As Single, penetrationPlan As Single, _ 
    renewalRate As Single, renewalPlan As Single, dealerRank As Single, _ 
    premiumDynamic As Single) As Single
    Dim Total As Single
    Total = 0
    If penetration >= penetrationPlan Then Total = Total + 0.01
    If renewalRate >= renewalPlan Then Total = Total + 0.01
    Select Case dealerRank
    Case 1
        Select Case premiumDynamic
            Case 0 To 0.03: Total = Total + 0.01
            Case 0.03 To 0.05: Total = Total + 0.02
            Case 0.05 To 1: Total = Total + 0.03
        End Select
    Case 2
        Select Case premiumDynamic
            Case 0.02 To 0.04: Total = Total + 0.01
            Case 0.04 To 0.08: Total = Total + 0.02
            Case 0.08 To 1: Total = Total + 0.03
        End Select
    Case 3
        Select Case premiumDynamic
            Case 0.05 To 0.1: Total = Total + 0.01
            Case 0.1 To 0.15: Total = Total + 0.02
            Case 0.15 To 1: Total = Total + 0.05
        End Select
    Case 4
        Select Case premiumDynamic
            Case 0.1 To 0.17: Total = Total + 0.01
            Case 0.17 To 0.25: Total = Total + 0.02
            Case 0.25 To 1: Total = Total + 0.03
        End Select
    Case 5
        Select Case premiumDynamic
            Case 0.15 To 0.3: Total = Total + 0.01
            Case 0.3 To 0.4: Total = Total + 0.02
            Case 0.4 To 1: Total = Total + 0.03
        End Select
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I recommend giving input that causes the described result. Or are you saying that the function always gives 0? Is this the entire function? You need to return the value with a line like `insurancebonus = Total`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't told the function to return anything.

I assume you want to return the value of `Total`?

If that is the case, prior to the `End Function` add the following line:

`insurancebonus = Total`

This specifies that your function should return the value of `Total`.

As a very short and contrived example, this function simply returns 1.

```
Public Function test() As Integer
    test = 1
End Function
```

The point is that you must assign the value to the name of your function.

For completeness, if your function returns an Object type you must use the `Set` keyword, such as:

```
Public Function testRange() As Range
    Set testRange = Range("A1")
End Function
```

Which would return a Range object.

Comment: Thanks so much! Well it's a mistake of a beginner and I've been trying to solve this problem for past 20 minutes. Thank a lot!

Comment: No problem!  Sometimes it's simply a matter of getting someone else's eyes on your code.  I've nearly pulled my own hair out with VBA and someone glances over my shoulder and points to a simple answer.  To be honest, those are the best kinds!